# Why is my button not displayed on a single line?

Tags: html, css

I have a button that gets displayed on the first line for about 90% of its width. The rest is getting displayed on the bottom line.

Maybe it's a silly thing that is causing this, but for some reason, I couldn't figure it out. It seems like the button will get displayed the same no matter where the webpage is placed.

You can find bellow the HTML and CSS code.

[image]

```
<div class="about__box-buttonBox">
       <a href="#about__box" id="collectionButton" class="button1"
        onclick="fadeIn()">Colecţie</a>
</div>

  about__box-buttonBox {
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    text-shadow: .1rem .1rem $color-silver-1;

}
.button1 {
    text-decoration: none;
    padding: 1rem;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-size: 1.3rem;
    color: $color-silver-3;
    letter-spacing: .2rem;
    border: outset $color-silver-3 .2rem;
    border-radius: .5rem;
    background-color: #FDF2FF;
}
```

Comment: The code you have provided does not show the same issue as the screenshot. Could it be the width of the container that the button is in restricting how wide it can go?

Comment: I've just added a new picture. The width of the container is set to 100%.

Comment: There is no problem with the code you provided, try to add a snippet or the button wrapper as well for better understanding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The width of the container is entirely different than the width of its child. A child doesn't necessarily inherit the width of its parent.

If you want the box to expand the whole width of the container, set the display to block, and width to 100%.